# JPA where in sub query

Tags: java, jpa

```
  public class Emp {
      Integer eid;
      String ename;
      long sal;
      Dept dept;    
    }

    public class Dept {
      Integer deptid;
      String deptname;
    }

     (List<Emp>) em.createQuery("select e from Emp e where e.sal=(select em.sal from Emp where em.eid=:a "))
                     .setParameter("a",empid)
                     .getResultList();
```

I want get all matched Emp list by passing emp id. Is it possible in Jpa. Please help me.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? Do you want to search on the basis of your Primary key?

Comment: You would have only `one Employee` for a particular `empId`. what do you want to fetch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. And you may try this;

```
  select e1 from Emp e1,Emp e2 where e1.sal = e2.sal and e2.eid =: a;
```